# hdiutil failing on macOS Catalina with a write error when creating a file on a network drive. The error does not happen on macOS mojave

Tags: macos-catalina, hdiutil

hdiutil fails when trying to create a dmg file at a network location on macOS Catalina. This error does not happen if I try to create the file locally in the temp directory.

```
cd <network drive>/installers;hdiutil convert -format UDRO -o "target_installer.dmg" "/var/folders/yn/df881_294gzdxbdt5kyttgw400003_/T/installer_DBwJn/target_installer.dmg"

Error Converting the dmg from srcfolder  
Mon Oct 30 12:26:50 2023 Preparing imaging engine…
Reading Protective Master Boot Record (MBR : 0)…
Mon Oct 30 12:26:50 2023 Error Converting the dmg from srcfolder
```

I am also able to modify binaries/dylibs on a network drive without any issues while the hdiutil command is erroring out in the other terminal window. Interestingly the error goes away with a restart, only to reappear after a few successful attempts.

I have tried this command locally and it works. So I am not sure why this fails and then passes on a machine restart. This error didn't happen with mojave.

Comment: wrong site - Stack Overflow is for *programming* Q&A. Maybe try on [apple.se] - just read the guidelines there first.